# Capture reload/endrequest event after server redirect to download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, redirect, download

Inside a webpage I have an Excel download button, which redirects to a webpage that serves the requested Excel file via the `application/ms-excel` MIME type, which usually results in a file download in the browser.

In the webpage, I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".div-export .button").click(function () { setBusy(true); });
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () { 
        setBusy(false);
    });
});
```

Which displays a busy animation while the user waits for the Excel file to be served.

Problem is: The animation doesn't end (`setBusy(false);`) after the file download, because the `endRequest` event doesn't get fired, probably because of the server redirect.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

**Edit**: The download button is handled in an `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a server redirect, I've decided to use a javascript document redirect that is triggered after the mouse cursor is reset. To do this, I've included a hidden field that holds the url:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hidExportUrl" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
```

Which is handled by the client-side `end_request` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".div-export .button").click(function () { setBusy(true); });

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () { 
        setBusy(false);

        var url = $("[id$='hidExportUrl']").val();

        if (url && url != "") {
            $("[id$='hidExportUrl']").val("");
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If for instance you have a popup, defined:

```
var myWindow = window.open("/MyPopup.aspx, "myWindow",
"height=550,width=780,top=100,left=100");
```

Try something like:

```
$(myWindow).bind('unload', function(){setBusy(false)});
```

Comment: It's not a popup in my case (our clients use agressive pop-up blockers), and the unload event isn't triggered here, because the page isn't unloaded by the browser.